# node-mysql won't connect with password

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am trying to connect to a local MySQL server using node-mysql, and having very little success.

Every time I try to connect, I get ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR. I have validated that I can connect to the MySQL server using the command line and the credentials below, that server is running, and the port is correct.

My code is below:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var dbConnection = mysql.createConnection( {
        user: 'node_user',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'sample_db',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306
        } );

dbConnection.connect(function(err) {
        if(err) {
                console.log('Can\'t connect');
                console.dir(err);
        } else {
                console.log('Connection success.');
                dbConnection.end();
        }
});
```

I'm sure that I'm doing something very obviously wrong, but I've been staring at it for most of the morning and I can't see what's wrong.

The only clue that I've got is that if I set the user's password to be blank (in the database and the code) then it connects quite happily.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'd check the permissions GRANTed to that user and IP address in the database.

Comment: I've granted the user all privileges on \*.\*  and granted login from %, which should give it access from all IP addresses. It still won't connect unless I null the password, in which case it connects fine.

Comment: Did you create a user and password and give them access?  I usually do.  I don't use the root password.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you take out the `database: sample_db`?  After connecting you can do `dbConnection.query('use sample_db');`.  I wonder if maybe it's not working because those are or are not root priveledges and on a specific database that user doesn't exist.

You shouldn't need to include port as it defaults to 3306.

Comment: "You shouldn't need to include port as it defaults to 3306." - there's nothing wrong with including it, and that's not the reason for failing to connect.

Comment: @Funkodebat unfortunately not - taking the database out doesn't allow it to connect.

Comment: @duffymo I'd say redundant code is wrong.  You could have a bunch of code that says `if ( true )` and it's not wrong, but not needed.  I didn't say it was the cause, but it's not needed.

@comish it sounds like a user problem if you can null the password and still connect.  Your problem doesn't exist in the code, it exists in mysql, try recreating the user.

Comment: @Funkodebat - thanks, I think it's something to do with either my Node or the MySQL installation on my laptop. If I run the same code on one of my AWS linux boxes then it connects successfully, but on my local mac I get the access denied error. Suspect it may be time to reinstall MySQL on the laptop.

Comment: @Funkodebat - sorry, adding the port is not the same as "a bunch of code".  It's arguably better documentation to make it clear to the developer that the default port is being used.  And, as you've noted, the comment neither adds no value here nor fixes the problem.

Comment: k go ahead and argue, i'm out

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial does not look like your code:

http://markshust.com/2013/11/07/creating-nodejs-server-client-socket-io-mysql

Where is the connection made?

Try it his way and see if that sorts you out.